# Writing larger integers as binary and reading them back gives bad result

Tags: c++

I have made a little program that writes an integer to a .bin file and then reads it back out. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
ofstream f("out.bin", ios::binary);
int a = 1496;
char x;

f.write((char*)&a, 4);
f.close();

ifstream in("out.bin", ios::binary);
in.read((char*)&x, 4);
cout << (int)x;
in.close();

return 0;}
```

The above code (writing the number 1496) returns -40 in the console. What could the problem be? Thanks!

Comment: `char x` has only space for one byte instead of four. Did you mean `int x`?

Comment: Have you tried making `x` an `int` ?

Comment: You are writing 4 bytes (int) and reading into char which is one byte

Comment: This is [typo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ywoKKQ3rDm56Fcgg).

Comment: In addition to the above, reading 4 bytes into a one-byte variable overwrites memory right after this variable. This can cause anywhere from a crash to no effect depending on where your 'x' variable is located in memory. In this case, it is the stack.

Comment: `f.write((char*)&a, 4);` -- In addition to the other comments, you should be using `sizeof(int)`, not a hard-coded `4`.

Answer (score 0):

```
f.write((char*)&a, 4);
```

You want to read 4 chars worth of data into `a` but `a` is a char and cannot store more than 1 char worth of data. This is the problem.

Comment: Why did you delete your answer on my question?

Comment: Because it was for C++ not C and I did not realize that until you pointed out.

Comment: well I don't know about any C specific libraries that can run Javascript code :(

Comment: I still have access to the answer, because when I saw the _This post has been deleted and is no longer viewable_ banner, I chose not to reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

In this line

`in.read((char*)&x, 4);`

you fill the bytes read from the stream into an array located at &x, however x is a char, thus has a size of 1 byte. This can lead to very unexpected results since unwanted memory changes can occur.

For your code to work all that's necessary is to change x's type from char to int.